# Insert Into Temp table multiple select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 select statements below which I would like to show the output like below. Currently, I am unable to join first query with second.

```
fanme   lname  JobTitle   AcceptanceRate
Jim    Cary     Manager    0.666666
```

```
   select fname, lname, JobTitle
   from [User]
   where userID=8
```

```
Select convert(decimal, x.QuoteAccepted) / y.AllQuotes as  AcceptanceRate 
from  (
    select count(*) as QuoteAccepted
    from Quote
    where ProjectManager_UserID=8 and QuoteStatusID=6
) x
join (
    select count(*) as AllQuotes
    from Quote
    where ProjectManager_UserID=8
) 
y on 1=1
```

I tried creating temp tables and insert into but it kept showing error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @Dale K, I added what expected output should look like

Comment: Also need sample data used to generate that/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select u.*,
       (select avg(case when q.QuoteStatusID = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) as QuoteAccepted
        from Quote q
        where q.ProjectManager_UserID = u.userId
       ) as AcceptanceRate
from users u
where u.UserID = 8
```

If you want this for all project managers:

```
select ProjectManager_UserID,
       avg(case when QuoteStatusID = 6 then 1.0 else 0 end) as AcceptanceRate
from Quote
group by ProjectManager_UserID;
```

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to join ProjectManager_UserID with UserID in User table so I can get, Name and job Title, as listed in the top of the questions. So I can see name, job title and AcceptanceRate

Comment: Wait, Even though its selecting as QuoteAccepted, it says No column Name ? For Bottom Query its showing QuoteAccepted but not for top Query

Comment: The bottom query is just for the user ids.  The first query answers the question you have asked here.

Comment: nvmd, Its Working!

Comment: Hey Gordon, Would it be possible to show result for all Managers instead of UserID=8? so basically a mix of top and bottom query? I stared at it for an hour but couldn't figure it out. If you can help, that would be kind of you :)

Comment: @NebelzCheez . . . You can just remove the `where` clause from the first query.

Comment: Removing where clause shows me acceptance rate for everyone in User table and not just Managers

Comment: @NebelzCheez . . . Add a `where` clause if you just want managers.

Comment: Hey yea, mvmd I got it to work. I did where userID in (select ProjectManager_UserID from quote). I tried this last night but wasn't getting right result. There was error in Data